# Форматирование сообщений для ICQ-клиента на PHP

Tags: icq, php

Ребята, нужна помощь.

Я пишу ICQ-Клиент на PHP и столкнулся с такой вот проблемой. Вот кусочек кода:

```
// Отправляем сообщение админу, что бот успешно подключился
$icq->sendMessage($array['admin_icq'], "Привет, Хозяин! Кажется, все работает.");
$icq->sendMessage($array['admin_icq'], "echo '123';");
```

У меня выходит следующее:

```
тест (17:17:54 1/08/2011)
Привет, Хозяин! Кажется, все работает.
тест (17:17:54 1/08/2011)
echo '123';
```

А хотелось бы, чтобы выходило так:

```
тест (17:17:54 1/08/2011)
Привет, Хозяин! Кажется, все работает.
тест (17:17:54 1/08/2011)
123
```

Кто хорошо знает синтаксис в php - просьба помочь. Заранее спасибо. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$var = 'ololo';

ob_start();
echo '321';
$var2 = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$icq->sendMessage($array['admin_icq'], '123 '.date('H:i:s').' '.$var.' '.$var2);
```

Разбирайте, смотрите функции на [php.net](http://php.net)

Answer (score 0):

Уберите echo, оставьте 123, по аналогии с предыдущим сообщением.

Comment: А вот и нет! А как я буду выводить дату? И выполнять другие функции? Мне нужно сделать именно этим способом..

Comment: А как вы '`Привет, Хозяин! Кажется, все работает.`' выводите? Там-то вы echo не используете.

Comment: Читай выше